# auto refresh of page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to refresh the page based on value selected. Initially i had set the meta tag to refresh the page for 10 secs. Later when a particular value is selected from combo, the page should get refreshed based on the value selected.
There is a buildchart function which gets executed when i load the page or when refreshed. This function gets a json file from a location. The json file gets updated every few minutes. So after few intervals i will be getting the updated json file in a configured location . So i am configuring a combo box with values so that when the user selects the value, after that much secs  the json is fetched and the report displayed.

HTML

```
<meta id="refresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=/index.html#/Refresh">
```

Later in the code:

```
    <select style="text-align: right;"  name="refreshrate" 
ng-model="model.refreshrate" 
ng-options= "item.value as item.label  for item in refreshValues "  
ng-change = "TimedRefresh(model.refreshrate)">

 </select>
```

My angular code

```
$scope.refreshValues =
            [
            {label:"1 Min", value:"1"},
            {label:"3 Min", value:"3"},
            {label:"5 Min", value:"5"},
            {label:"Never", value:"0"}
        ];

        $scope.TimedRefresh = function(t) {
                console.log(t);
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t*60);
        }
```

However, the page refreshes with the already configured value of 10 in the meta tag's content. what am i missing to update this?

**UPDATE**

I tried changing the meta tag during runtime when the value is selected, now the page refresh happens but only once at the specified selected interval and not repeatedly after that.

```
$scope.TimedRefresh = function(t) {
            console.log(t);
        var s = document.getElementById('refresh');

         s.setAttribute("content", t*10 +";URL=index.html#/Refresh");

        console.log(s);
    }
```

I removed the content attribute from the meta tag and assigned it at runtime. However i am trying to refresh the page not once but every configured interval times.

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page?

Comment: Remove the meta tag? But why refresh at all? Let Angular do all the work.

Comment: i removed the meta tag but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$route.reload(); or $window.location.reload();
```

Comment: i changed the code from setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t*60); to setTimeout($route.reload(true),t*10); Still not working

Answer (score 0):

The meta-tag will refresh the page no matter what. You should call `TimedRefresh(10)` in the controller, so when it loads, the function get called.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {

    $scope.refreshValues = [
        {label:"1 Min", value:"1"},
        {label:"3 Min", value:"3"},
        {label:"5 Min", value:"5"},
        {label:"Never", value:"0"}
    ];

    $scope.TimedRefresh = function(t) {
            console.log(t);
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t*60);
    }

    $scope.TimedRefresh(10); // Will trigger TimedRefresh(10) once when the controller loads

    // ...
});
```

I'm curious on what you are trying to do though. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i am drawing a report using d3 in a div and after every interval i would fetch the latest values to redraw the report. On each refresh this should happen.

Comment: Angular should help you do that without having to refresh the page. See [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for fetching data and [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to do it on a regular interval.